# What is the difference between GCRS and J2000 frames?

Tags: jpl-horizons, skyfield, frames

What is the difference between GCRS and J2000 frames?
Which is commonly used worldwide in satellite communications?

I've read a statement [here](https://github.com/skyfielders/python-skyfield/blob/master/skyfield/documentation/earth-satellites.rst), that `GCRS coordinates are based on even more precise axes than those of the old J2000 system.` However, the JPL Horizons shows results in J2000 frame.

About the difference between GCRS and ITRS: is GCRS an ECI frame, and ITRS is an ECEF frame?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Second question first:

> About the difference between GCRS and ITRS: is GCRS an ECI frame, and ITRS is an ECEF frame?

Correct.

> What is the difference between GCRS and J2000 frames? Which is commonly used worldwide in satellite communications?

The difference is small. The GCRF frame is essentially the ICRF frame, but with a slightly different relativistic time scale. The JPL ephemerides (the underlying basis of JPL Horizons and JPL's SPICE system) treat the J2000 frame and the ICRF frames as equivalent. The ephemerides aren't precise enough to see the difference between the hundredths of arc second difference between the J2000 and ICRF frames. With regard to satellite communications, the beamwidths of the antennae used for deep space communication are over ten times the small discrepancy between the J2000 and ICRF frames; even the uncertainty in antenna pointing exceeds this small discrepancy. For near Earth satellites (where the GCRF is more applicable than the ICRF), beamwidths are even wider.

Comment: Thanks! So, GCRS is different from J2000, and both are different from ICRS? :) Why GCRS is more applicable than ICRF and J2000?

Comment: In theory, all reference frames are equally valid; you could use Neptune-centered inertial frame to model the behavior of a satellite in low Earth orbit or Earth weather. In practice, some reference frames are better than others, depending on the application. An Earth-centered inertial frame is more applicable to satellites orbiting the Earth than is a solar system barycenter-based frame frame (or a Neptune-centered inertial frame), just as an Earth-centered, Earth-fixed frame is better than an Earth-centered inertial frame for modeling what happens near the surface of or inside of the Earth.

Comment: I mean ICRS, GCRS and J2000 all are Earth Centered Inertial frames. Is GCRS more applicable for Earth satellites? Is it widely used in practice? And why is it 'better'?

Comment: @DavidHammen I also suspect there might be something insightful behind your parenthetical in the last sentence that we are not getting yet. "(GCRF is more applicable than the ICRF)" though it may turn out to be obvious in hindsight.

Comment: @uhoh -=One of my personal favorite tests as a key developer of a dynamics software package used widely across JSC was to model the orbit of an object about the Moon in Moon-centered vs Earth-centered vs Earth-Moon barycenter vs Neptune inertial vs solar system barycenter inertial coordinates. In theory, all of those frames are equally valid. In practice, only one did a good job of approximating reality -- and that one (Moon-centered inertial, duh) required a good solar system barycenter model of the orbits of the potentially disrturbing bodies.

Comment: @Leeloo so maybe a good way to think is rather than focus on asking which is more applicable, better, or widespread, it's much more educational to try doing a few calculations using different options to see in your particular case if it makes any difference or not, and if so find another calculation to compare against. Being able to answer "is this working" and "is this better or worse" yourself is much more valuable than doing things the way it is said that other people do it. Run your calculation and get a feel for how much accuracy you will need, then change frames and see what happens.

Comment: @Leeloo It reminds me a bit of this [question](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/25807/12102) which at the end asks "What is the best interpolator that I should use?" and really it should ask "What are three good interpolators that I can compare?" In Python there is EAFP "Easier to Ask for Forgiveness than Permission" [1](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12265451/3904031), [2](https://docs.quantifiedcode.com/python-anti-patterns/readability/asking_for_permission_instead_of_forgiveness_when_working_with_files.html), [3](https://docs.python.org/3.6/glossary.html) i.e. try first then see what happens!

Comment: @uhoh I implemented in J2000 and in GCRS. Got a little difference in z-axis. However, I didn't ask which is better. I asked, which is widely used, which is standart for Earth satellite communications? As David stated, I could also use a Neptune inertial frame, however it would be bizarre if my soft by default calculates in this frame ;)

Comment: @DavidHammen I think this question is related, because poliastro uses the default epoch of J2000 when defining/propagating orbits, yet it also depends on astropy, which is in lockstep with IERS; please have a look-see and answer if you can: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63580791/which-inertial-reference-frames-eci-coordinates-does-poliastro-return-out-of